# Booking GEM recommendation - Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

could one recommend a very good gem for creating a booking system.

i would like to create a similar website such as www.airbnb.co.uk where users can book dates to rent an item (where as in the case of airbnb its booking an apartment). there are many out there, but if one could recommend a good gem i would very grateful

i have come across the below gem: 
[bookable](https://github.com/kunks001/bookable)

#### Task

i am building an app that allows users to rent an item and book the dates to rent that item.

Comment: Why do you need a gem for that , you can create the same app using basic gems such as devise and cancan too .

Comment: thank you, i'm new to rails and just needed advise on the best way to go about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build a site like airbnb , you will need 2 set of users . Let's say renters and buyers . You can create different users using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) . Devise provides a lot of in built goodies that would help you get up and started easily . Next you would need something to check for roles and authorization , you can look into either [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) or [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) whichever suits your need . For payment purpose , you can use Stripe which has detailed documentation and can be up and working quickly :)

Comment: what about the booking gem? did you use bookable or maybe you found another alternative? I am very interested in this question too. Thanks!